# Dell 6850 disk configuration

Tags: diskmanagement

Just bought a server to load SP2010 onto, for intranet and external website.
5  new disks installed, and not sure how to configure
I created one array of all 5, and then made into a logical drive
However when I try to load windows, there is no drive to select???
Any help most welcome
G

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the drivers for the RAID controller during the install. The easiest way to do this is to use the Dell supplied system build DVD to install Windows. If you don't have the DVD that should have come with the system you can download the ISO image and burn it to DVD from here:

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=NF1CT&FileId=2731102793

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Dell Drivers&Downloads](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriversHome/NeedProductSelection), select your model or enter your Service Tag, download a driver disk, and make Windows load the PERC driver. After that, it should be possible to install.

If you still have problems, try to ask a more specific question, including what you have tried, and any error messages and such.

Answer (score 0):

as the server is booting up, you have to hit the hotkey for the server's RAID configuration utility and create a logical drive. then when you start the Windows install, there's at 50/50 chance you will also need to provide drivers for your RAID controller.